# Fix the background image in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In all browser I use the following css rules, and it works

```
// it fits the background image to container
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover;
```

Are there css rules to make it work in IE8 also, or should I use javascript?

In case of javascript I am using jquery.
What is the best way to active my goal?

Comment: The best way in IE8? Well, probably a stretched `img` tag as IE8 won't resize `background-image`s

Comment: how should I stretch the background image? I mean I can do `$(body).css('background-image')` and then?

Answer (score 2):

I had also the same problem but by going through this below link my problem solved

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: This is the best reference I have found for full page BG images

Answer (score 1):

There's a [jQuery plugin](http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/) or this [javascript fallback](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) with filter

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Check the [same page for more](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) cross-browser methods

Comment: +1 thanks for your response. let's suppose the image is external how should I change src='.myBackground.jpg'?

Comment: Hi @LorraineBernard, i think you can just change it to `src='http://etc.com/myImage.jpg'` . Check the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532920(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f156/Bob_McBobBob/Awesome_Background_by_smirfy.jpg" class="bgimg" />
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="contents">
    page contents
    page contents
    page contents
    page contents
    page contents
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html {
 background:#000; 
}

html, body { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
}

.bgimg {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.frame {
  color:white;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.contents {
 padding:10px; 
}
```

demo site: http://jsbin.com/enevov/1/edit

you can achieve different effects by changing
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
on .bgimg, to accomplish different effects, depending on whether you want a distortion or not, for instance just `width: 100%` will make it touch across the top, etc...

hope this helps -ck

Comment: width:100%; height:100%; does not maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to stretch image on full window in IE8

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/