# How can I fill an image to 100% in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

The background image stretches to fill the div perfectly in every other browser other than IE(running 8, have not tried other versions). Is there any way I can make this happen?

```
  #media { 
    background-image:url(Images/The_Great_Dividing_Range.JPG);  
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    height: auto;  
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix the background image in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958452/fix-the-background-image-in-ie8)

Comment: so i have to use javascript?

Comment: Yes. Something like this: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions on Stack about this already; one in particular that seems to be helpful to people is: [IE 8: background-size fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix) -- there's a MS filter hack as well as a polyfill listed -- hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look under CSS Only Technique #2:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/